# share on facebook messenger

Tags: ios, url-scheme, uidocumentinteraction, facebook-messenger

For an app I'm working on I'm integrating different social services the user can select to share the content created using the app.

What I'm trying to understand is if the facebook-messenger app expose an URL scheme that can be used to perform some action (basically texting one of his/her friend), or if there is a specific UTI that can be used in conjunction with the UIDocumentInteractionController.

Thanks in advance for any help / hint / suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Messenger URL scheme on iOS is fb-messenger://, I don't know if it's possible to open a composer that will let you choose contacts or pre fill it with a message.

You can open a conversation if you know the Facebook user ID: fb-messenger://user-thread/[facebook-user-id]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would not like to select a specific user . Anyway I'll mark your answer as correct since I did not specify exactly what were my needs

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compose message but you can send a link, photo or video via messenger.
Facebook provides API for that.

Import FBSDKShareKit

```
#import <FBSDKShareKit.h>
```

Create content and share

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.url.com"];
content.contentTitle = @"My link!";
content.contentDescription = @"Check out my link!";

[FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

You also need to conform your controller to the FBSDKSharingDelegate

```
#pragma mark - FBSDKSharingDelegate

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results {

}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}

- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer {

}
```

Available contents are:

- FBSDKShareLinkContent
- FBSDKSharePhotoContent
- FBSDKShareVideoContent

Comment: It seems necessary to give a contentURL when sharing, but if I want to send a pure text message via Messenger, can I still use FBSDKMessageDialog?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Only available contents are Link, Photo and Video. If you skip url in Link content, the whole share content won't appear.

Comment: CAREFUL: using facebooks SDK means they will mine data from your users. Every single one of them